# mount option stripe not defined in fstab

Tags: linux, mount

I have an AWS instance.

Suddenly I can see this new mount option *stripe=32736*

```
/dev/xvdb on /var/lib/elasticsearch0 type ext4 (rw,relatime,stripe=32736,data=ordered)
/dev/xvdc on /var/lib/elasticsearch1 type ext4 (rw,relatime,stripe=32736,data=ordered)
```

But this option not appears in fstab

```
root@thorin:~# cat /etc/fstab
# HEADER: This file was autogenerated at 2017-09-12 16:38:10 +0200
# HEADER: by puppet.  While it can still be managed manually, it
# HEADER: is definitely not recommended.
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /       ext4    defaults,discard        0       0
/dev/xvdb       /var/lib/elasticsearch0 ext4    defaults        0       0
/dev/xvdc       /var/lib/elasticsearch1 ext4    defaults        0       0
11.0.0.228://el_backup  /srv/backup/el  nfs4    tcp,nolock,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,intr,noatime,actimeo=3       0       0
```

So, I have two questions.

1. Why have this happend?
2. How can I fix this?

Some time ago I fix this in another machine. I was something related with RAID headers. There was some tool to set stripe to 0 but I can't find this now.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions.

Comment: Serverfault would be a better place to ask questions like this but I'm pretty sure that whatever system you used to create the filesystem defined stripe settings when the filesystem was created. If `stripe` is not defined by the mount flags but the superblock contains information about historical stripe value, the value from superblock is automatically used. Having stripe setting is not important for data correctness, but it's just a performance hint for optimal storage access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can answer second question.

```
tune2fs -f -E stride=0 /dev/xvdb
```